# How to seal swamp cooler ducting into house siding?

Tags: exterior, evaporative-cooling

My swamp cooler enters the house horizontally through an exterior wall.  What is the correct way to seal this interface to the wood siding?  Should I just use an exterior caulking around the edges?

[image: swamp cooler interface]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick closed-cell backer rod into the larger gaps. Then caulk over everything (small gaps as well as the backer rod) with a good exterior-grade caulk that looks good color-wise when connecting them.